How to Prevent Clerk from Overwriting User Names on SSO Sign-In?
I'm using Clerk for authentication in my app and supporting SSO providers like Google. When a user signs up through Google, Clerk sets their first and last name based on their Google profile, which works as expected. However, I’m encountering an issue:
If a user updates their name within my app, Clerk resets their name to the one from their Google profile every time they sign in through Google. This behavior creates an inconsistent user experience because the app's stored name gets overwritten.
I would like to:

Allow Clerk to set the name only on the initial sign-up through Google.
Prevent Clerk from resetting the name on subsequent sign-ins.

If differentiation between sign-up and sign-in isn’t possible, I’d prefer to disable name syncing from SSO providers entirely.

Questions:

Is there a way to configure Clerk to handle names only during sign-up and not on sign-in?
If not, is there an option to completely disable Clerk from setting names from SSO providers?


Example Scenario:

A user signs up through Google. Clerk sets the name to "John Doe."
The user updates their name in my app to "Johnny."
The user signs in again through Google. Clerk resets the name to "John Doe," which is undesirable.


How can I achieve this?
